# ParseException error when trying to insert into spark table

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, insert, sql-insert

Trying to insert a pyspark dataframe, df as new records into an existing directory in spark

```
def path_exists(path):
  try:
    if len(dbutils.fs.ls(path)) > 0:
      return True
  except:
    return False

if (path_exists("abfss://famli-dev-workspace@famlisandbox.dfs.core.windows.net/path_to_table")) == True:
    df.write.mode("append").format("orc").insertInto("abfss://famli-dev-workspace@famlisandbox.dfs.core.windows.net/path_to_table")
```

But got this error:

```
ParseException: 
mismatched input ':' expecting {<EOF>, '.', '-'}(line 1, pos 5)
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

you have an **indentation problem**  [image: try this way]

Comment: which line is the indentation problem?

Comment: Starting from the first line , try to follow the photo in the answer